# Is that possible to show a context menu clicking the listview without longpress

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I searched many stackoverflow reference i didn't find no one related to my question.Is that possible to show a context menu clicking the listview items **without longpress** that is like single click.

Comment: Did you mean OnItemClickListener() ?

Comment: Why you are not using custom dialog fragment or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the Alert Dialog for this type. It should be efficient for this.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you call `registerForContextMenu(yourView)` then you can call `openContextMenu(yourView);` and it will open the `ContextMenu`.

I did it by declaring a function in xml for a `Button` then I register my `Button`. In the `onClick` I provided in xml I call `openContextMenu(v)` and it works. I had to do this to show `ContextMenu` for `API 10` and `PopUpMenu` for `API >= 11`

Answer (score 0):

You should try popupmenu, it''s even backported
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html